# Custom editor template not rendered / fired

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using custom templates within my MVC project to display various object types in different ways.  Some are working and others are not!  For any that don't work, they are being passed into my object.cshtml custom template rather than their own.

Here's an example.  In this example, I'm creating an address lookup type which I want to render a first line of address and postcode field with a lookup button.

My ViewModel has  the following:

```
namespace MyProject.Views
{
    public class AddressLookup
    {
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Address Lookup")]
        public AddressLookup addressLookup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
@model RegistrationViewModel
<div class="well" id="form-well">
    <h2>Register New User</h2>
    <h3>Step 1 of 3 - Login Details</h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterNewUser", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizonal" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        @Html.EditorForModel(Model);
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <div style="padding: 15px;" class="form-group col-md-offset-3">                
            <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

My AddressLookup.cshtml looks like this:

```
@using MyProject
@model AddressLookup

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstLine)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode)

<p>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="alert('lookup');" value="Add new address">Lookup address</button>
</p>
```

But when debugging, it runs the code in the object.cshtml in the EditorTemplates folder and not the one for AddressLookup.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Hmm, it looks like if I add a [UIHint("AddressLookup")] about the property, that's working.  Why would that be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a UIHint to the property in my view model worked (although I don't fully understand why).

```
namespace MyProject.Views
{
    public class AddressLookup
    {
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string FirstLine { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Address Lookup")]
        [UIHint("AddressLookup")]
        public AddressLookup addressLookup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks
Simon